# how to get div's background color translucent on hover by CSS?

Tags: css

What effect should I use to get that light white layer on the top?Please see the picture attached.
I have used opacity but did not help !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxzVX.jpg

They are codes I have tryed but did not work !

```
.email-title{
             opacity: .50; /* Standard: FF gt 1.5, Opera, Safari, CSS3 */
            filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* IE lt 8 */
            -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=50)"; /* IE 8 */
            -khtml-opacity: .50; /* Safari 1.x */
            -moz-opacity: .50; /* FF lt 1.5, Netscape */
            cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: I did not ask anyone to write me codes I asked about the effect that I should Use !

Comment: Which is the same thing.

Comment: You may also want to include `-webkit-opacity`, and `opacity` should be `0.50`, not `.50`.